# compiling LibXML2 in VC2005/08 and Mac Os env

Tags: windows, linux, visual-studio-2008, libxml2, osx-leopard

I am writing a C application which uses LibXML2 for XML parsing and Validation. Compiling it in Linux was pretty easy, though compiling it in Windows and Mac seems to be exacting.

For Windows, I am using VC2005/08 ( I basically have both the copies, hence would use on which ever its easier). I need to compile my application along with Libxml2 and other libraries. *Most Importantly I need to compile this with MSVCRT.DLL and not with other CRT DLL Libraries like MSVCRT71.dll etc...*

I need to build this for Mac Os as well.

Please advice on how should I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time I setup a Visual C++ 2005 project file to build libxml2 from source.  Amazingly I kept instructions on how I did some of it.  This is for 2.7.4, so it may be different for the current version.

First you have to run the configure script; I did `cscript configure.js iconv=no` as I didn't want to complicate things with another dependency (iconv).  This generates some header files that define what options are available for the build.

Then you need to create a project file and add all the libxml2 source files to it.  I set mine up as a static library that linked with the static C runtime, though you may want to change this for your needs.  I had to add some definitions to my project file so that it would build a certain way; looking at my project file I see `_REENTRANT;HAVE_WIN32_THREADS`.  I don't remember what these mean, but I probably gleaned them from the makefile.

That's really all there is to it; configure, add the files, and set some defines.

Comment: You need to apply this patch to fix the Windows build: http://git.gnome.org/browse/libxml2/commit/?id=364e3d2b054656f2cf97594365d15b2ddb72a9ed